# TypeOrm - How to run raw sql query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

Before I was using typeorm `v0.2.25`

There I used to run raw queries like this:

```
const users = await getManager().query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

But since now I update typeOrm to latest version: `v0.3.10`

How can I achieve same raw query in the latest version.

Since in very latest version `getManager()` is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) says:

- getManager(), getMongoManager(), getSqljsManager(), getRepository(), getTreeRepository(), getMongoRepository(), createQueryBuilder() are all deprecated now. Use globally accessible data source instead:

  ```
   export const myDataSource = new DataSource({ /*...*/ })
   export const Manager = myDataSource.manager
   export const UserRepository = myDataSource.getRepository(UserEntity)
   export const PhotoRepository = myDataSource.getRepository(PhotoEntity)
   // ...
  ```

So your code could look like this:

```
    const UserRepository = myDataSource.getRepository(UserEntity);
    const users = await UserRepository.query("SELECT * FROM users");
```